# ViewModels and DTO mixed with repository pattern

Tags: repository-pattern

Some parts in our project's codebase implement the repository pattern in a different way from
[what we usually do](https://web.archive.org/web/20210311104642/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

**Here's the example**

```csharp
public class Repository : IRepository
{
   public Repository(AppDbContext dbContext, Mapper mapper)
   {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
       _mapper = mapper;
   }

   public IQueryable<DTO> Get() =>
       _dbContext.Entities
       .ProjectTo<DTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

   public async Task<DTO> GetAsync(Guid identity)
   {
       var entity = await _dbContext.Entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == identity);
       return _mapper.Map<DTO>(entity);
   }

   // One variant
   public async Task<DTO> CreateOrUpdateAsync(Guid identity, ViewModel model)
   {
        var entity = await _dbContext.Entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == identity);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = new Entity();
            entity.Id = identity;
            _dbContext.Add(entity);
        }

        _mapper.Map(model, entity);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return _mapper.Map<DTO>(entity);
   }

   // Other variant.
   public async Task<DTO> CreateOrUpdateAsync(ViewModel model)
   {
        var entity = await _dbContext.Entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.Id);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = new Entity();
            entity.Id = identity;
            _dbContext.Add(entity);
        }

        _mapper.Map(model, entity);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return _mapper.Map<DTO>(entity);
   }
}
```

Clearly there is quite a chunk of logic being shoveled into the repository.

This is not used in any unit-of-work and it usually gets injected straight into the controller.

**Example of controller that uses the repository**

```csharp
public class SomeController : Controller
{

  private readonly IRepository _repository;

  [HttpPut]
  public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync(
    [FromRoute] Guid referencedObjectId, [FromBody] ViewModel model)
  {
      // some permission check

      var output = await _repository.CreateOrUpdateAsync(referencedObjectId, model);
      return Ok(output);
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromRoute] Guid id)
  {
      // some permission check

      var entity = await _repository.GetAsync(id);
      return entity;
  }

}
```

I thought the repository could only work with an [Entity](https://web.archive.org/web/20210311141857/https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/basics/entity-in-entityframework.aspx) and any mapping must happen outside of its scope (i.e., perhaps controller, wrapped service).

Is it a code smell?

What are the pros/cons to this approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated in another answers, repositories are aimed to avoid you application to know implementation details of  how your app entities are stored in a database, text file, whatever.

Answering your question, I don’t see a problem while involving DTOs in the repository pattern if you need them to pass or get information related to your domain.

Maybe you are seeing a problem, because they remind a common problem related: “Using  data classes as your domain entities” ( entity framework generated ones,for example) Therefore If you choose to avoid reusing  data classes as domain entities, then you should perform an internal mapping  between them, which is totally fine.

Hope I solved your doubts